# Creating a standalone linux exe from Python code

Tags: python

We are trying to create a single standalone exe version of our Python application which will run on Ubuntu versions 16.x to 22.x and also on RedHat 7.2.

Currently we're building on Ubuntu 22.04 using a two step process

1. PyInstaller to make a single exe (this includes bundling some other binary tools that our app uses)
2. staticx to statically link all libraries that the exe uses.

However we are seeing problems. E.g. when running on Ubuntu 16.04 and spawning the binary tools, we get errors like:

/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIvDsZl/libgcc_s.so.1)

So the binary tool is using the libgcc_s.so.1 bundled by staticx but then it requires a libc.so.6 that doesn't exist.

I've tried adding the libc.so.6 from the build machine using staticx's -l argument but that seems to make no difference.

So

1. Does anyone know how we can get staticx to produce an exe that will work in this situation?
2. Are there any alternatives to staticx that will produce an exe that will work for all our OSs, including bundling and spawning the binary tools?

Comment: pyinstaller's executable _isn't_ a real standalone executable -- it's an archive with a bunch of other files inside it; staticx doesn't know that, so it doesn't do anything about shared libraries that are linked not by the wrapper but by its contents.

Comment: Honestly, my strong recommendation is _don't try_. Better packaging systems like [Nix](https://nixos.org/) let you reliably build and install software on any distro or Unixlike OS you want _without_ needing to produce a single executable; your dependencies end up in locations like `/nix/store/glibc-<hash>/...` where nothing that isn't installed by Nix will know or care about their presence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is more an issue with PyInstaller than StaticX (though we never had a problem when just using PyInstaller). This solves the problem:

https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html?highlight=LD_LIBRARY_PATH#ld-library-path-libpath-considerations